# Differencing a random walk process in time series

Tags: time-series

How do you Difference a random walk process to make it stationary.

Comment: are you asking what does "difference" mean when applied to a series?  Are you asking "what is stationarity"?  Are you asking why difference impacts stationarity, or how to measure stationarity before and after differencing?

Answer (score 4):

A random walk process is defined as
$$
X_t = X_{t-1} + Z_t,
$$
where $\{Z_t\}$ is white or IID noise.

Using just pencil and paper, you can see that subtracting $X_{t-1}$ from both sides tells you the differenced series is IID or White Noise. Each random variable in this white noise process has mean zero, and the covariance function is zero for all lags that aren't zero. So differencing a random walk makes a new process that is in particular stationary.

You might know this already. With a computer, if you have a series stored, then you need to subtract from each value (except the first) the previous value. This will give you the noise series that might be more amenable to modeling. If you're using `R` check out the function `diff`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to substract the value of your function at time t with the value of the function at time t-1. If this operation give you a constant value over all t, then you have a random walk process

http://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411arim.htm

Comment: If the first difference is a constant, then you don't have a random walk: you have a linear function.