# How many "effective" observations from sliding window sampling?

Tags: correlation, degrees-of-freedom, random-walk, overlapping-data

I have data on the trajectory of a particle and am interested in the displacement of the particle in a given time period. In particular, I have information on how much a particle has moved in each second, i.e. in the first second it moved by 1 m and the second second it moved by 2 m.

To obtain observations of the total displacement in a given time period using a sliding window approach (so if the trajectory is 10 seconds long and I am looking at a time period of 2 seconds, then I have 9 observations of this total displacement). However, the samples will be correlated as they overlap, is there a way to determine the number of "effective" independent observations of the displacement?

Currently, I am using the number of independent time origins which appears to underestimate the variance in the displacement.

Comment: Is it a random walk? Brownian motion? If so, have you tried differencing it or some similiar?

Comment: It is a random walk. Differencing?

Comment: See [Differencing a random walk process in time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297642/differencing-a-random-walk-process-in-time-series).

Comment: Differencing to remove the correlation?

Comment: To make the time series stationary, deal with the autocorrelation issue.

Comment: Sorry I am not really clear how this solves the problem. Are you proposing that I make the walk stationary before I calculate the displacements?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am suggesting. Estimating dispersion on autocorrelated data is erroneous. Removing this autocorrelation will give you a better picture of how your particle moves, maybe.

Comment: I don't really see the difference between finding displacements and making the walk stationary...sorry I might be being daft.

Comment: why don't you write out your calculations mathematically, It's not clear what you are trying to calculate.

Comment: "and am interested in the displacement of the particle in a given time period" like, you want to determine the diffusion speed based on statistics about the distance traveled with each single step?

Comment: Why are you complicating the issue by looking at 9 overlapping intervals of 2 seconds instead of 10 intervals of 1 second? (this doesn't invalidate the question, sometimes one might have correlated data, but in this particular case there seems to be a simple solution by just reverting to the original data.)

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I have added a clarification to the text. I want to know the displacement that occurs after 2 seconds (not 1 second) so there is not the option to simplify as you suggest. I could only look at non-overlapping points (but that throws away a lot of data which is problematic if I want to investigate the total displacement over 9 seconds).

Comment: *"I want to know the displacement that occurs after 2 seconds"* you can model this based on the distribution of the displacements that occur in 1 seconds. What you want to find out is the parameters of the model for the random walk and values like 'displacement after 2 seconds' are just derived from those underlying model parameters.